# How do I move Forward from Here?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Yeah, when I got the distress beacon that told me Artemis's name, I took the ship that was right next to it.  Not sure if I should have done that because everything needs repairing.  I didn't know I would lose my old ship.  I repaired thrusters and pulsers so I can fly, but I have no shield or hyperdrive.

Anyway, I have visited the anomaly, and I got the message from Artemis and my character said I need to help him and said something about boosting signals and searching the stars or something.  I have no idea what I 'm supposed to do next.  I found a freighteer with a NPC who wants to sell it but it costs too much.  What am I supposed to do?  Should I just start a new game?

Comment: Got my old ship back!  Pressed X, summon vehicle, change docked vehicle, and selected my old ship and now Ive got a fully functional one!

Comment: will play again tomorrow, see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you just went to the Space Anomaly for the first time. Upon leaving, Artemis contacts you but they are soon cut off. The quest description should update to:

> After returning to my ship, a stranger identifying themselves as Artemis contacted me. Static and interference rendered communication difficult, but it is clear that Artemis needs my help. I must find some way to boost the signal before it is too late.

At this point your objective is to find an Holo-Terminus. **Board you starship, go to space and perform a scan** - the quest should then progress and provide a waypoint to the terminal position on a planet in the current system.

Things to notice:

- you probably need to be in the same system you first got Artemis message in.
- if you are playing on one of the latest updates, it is very possible that the terminal waypoint won't take you directly to the terminal but to a nearby location. In that case, you will have to use the analysis scanner in sweeping mode to reach the actual location.

Comment: Tried it and it worked!  thnx.

Comment: @Millard my pleasure. BTW, notice that this procedure - go to space, perform scan - will be used frequently during this and other quest-lines. So, worth to keep that in mind in case you are stuck again